# using dfs to check if graph is bipartite

Tags: c++, graph-theory, directed-graph

```
class graph{
    void DFSutil(int v);

    public:
        
        map<int, vector<int> > adj;
        map<int, bool> visited;
        map<int, int> color;
        int twoteams = 1;
        
        void DFS();
        void addEdge(int u,int v);
        
        
};
```

this function adds edge to the graph

```
void graph::addEdge(int u,int v){
    
    adj[u].push_back(v);
    
}
```

depth first search function.
i tried to color the child as !parent
(in case im not wrong):
and if the color of child and parent is same, that means the graph is not bipartite

```
void graph::DFSutil(int v){
    
    visited[v] = true;
    
    for (auto i:adj[v]){
        if(visited[i]==false){
            
            color[i] = !color[v];
            DFSutil(i);
            
        }
        else if(color[i]==color[v]){
            
        twoteams = 0;
        return;
        }
    }
}
```

in case the graph has more than one connected component

```
void graph::DFS(){
    
    for (auto i:adj){
        if(!visited[i.first]) DFSutil(i.first);
    }
    
}
```

the graph is given as: B (a vector): [[1,2],[1,3]...]   the edges: 1-->2, 1-->3...

```
int Solution::solve(int A, vector<vector<int> > &B) {
    
    graph g;
    g.addEdge(B[0][0],B[0][1]);
    g.color[B[0][0]] = 1;
    int n = B.size();
    for (int i=1;i<n;++i){
        
        g.addEdge(B[i][0],B[i][1]);
        
    }
    g.DFS();
    return g.twoteams;
}
```

why does it not check if the graph is bipartite.
color stores the color of a node as 0 or 1;
it should return 0 if not bipartite and 1 otherwise

Answer (score 0):

To determine if a graph is bipartite it is sufficient to determine that the number of maximal cliques is exactly two.

Here is the pseudo code for finding the maximal cliques

```
LOOP
    CONSTRUCT empty current set
    SELECT V arbitrary vertex
    add V to current set
    remove V from graph
    LOOP      // while set is growing
        added_to_set = false
        LOOP V over vertices in graph
            LOOP Vset over current set
                IF Vset connected to V
                     add V to current set
                     remove V from graph
                     added_to_set = true
                     break;
        IF added_to_set == false
           break;    // the set is maximal
    ADD current set to list of sets
    IF graph has no remaining vertices
       OUTPUT sets found
       STOP
```

For a C++ implementation of this see code at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2/blob/dbd6ff06edabd6a6d35d5eb10ed7972dc2d779a6/src/cPathFinder.cpp#L483